# Parametric test for testing if two sets of samples came from the same normal distribution with unknown parameter?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, normal-distribution, kolmogorov-smirnov-test, nonparametric

Is there a parametric test to see if two sets of samples came from the same normal distribution with unknown parameter?

Suppose I have one set of samples $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_m$ and another set of samples $Y_1, Y_2, \dots, Y_n$.

Do we know a test to check if both of these were drawn from some normal distribution $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ where both $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ are unknown?

Comment: Aren't there two (or three) tests here. First, are the distributions normal. Second, are they from the same distribution?

Comment: If you assume normality, you could consider a likelihood ratio test, described in section 2 here: http://www.math.kit.edu/stoch/~klar/seite/veroeffentlichungen/media/two-sample-tests15-09-24.pdf

Comment: I think that what isn't clear is whether or not you are 1) initially trying to fit the two samples to normal distributions and then 2) if you don't reject normality you want to test that the two means and variances could be equal OR assuming before testing that both come from univariate normal distributions and only test that they have the same means and variances.  I think that is what Jeremy Miles, Eric Mittman and I are asking. If it is the second case Eric has a link to one possible solution.

Comment: Also in your title you mention parameter (singular).  Do you just want to test the mean or just the variance or more likely both?